# Can't assign PermissionSet but license is ok

Tags: unit-test, user, permission-sets

I'm trying to test a class that insert users and assigns a PermissionSet to them.

The method works fine in all orgs I've tested it in, however in the test class, I get an error.

The error reads :

```
Can't assign permission set to this user, user license doesn't match: []
```

The profile I assign to the user is the same profile required by the PermissionSet, this is why I don't understand the error.

What could I do to solve this issue ?

Source code :

```
@IsTest
public class UserHandlerTest {

    private static List<ContactWrapper> returnContactWrappers() {
        ContactWrapper cw  = new ContactWrapper('Random', 'Quidam', 'ralala@testemail.fr', '0601020304');
        ContactWrapper cw1 = new ContactWrapper('Quidam', 'Random', 'ralala1@testemail.fr', '0623331122');

        return new List<ContactWrapper> {cw, cw1};
    }

    private static User createUser() {

        UserRole ur = new UserRole(Name = 'TestRole', DeveloperName =  'TestRole');
        INSERT ur;

        User u = new User();
        u.UserRoleId = [SELECT Id FROM UserRole WHERE DeveloperName = 'TestRole' LIMIT 1].Id;
        u.ProfileID = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Administrateur système'].Id;
        u.EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1';
        u.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
        u.TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/New_York';
        u.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
        u.FirstName = 'first';
        u.LastName = 'last';
        u.Username = 'test@appirio.com';   
        u.CommunityNickname = 'testUser123';
        u.Alias = 't1';
        u.Email = 'no@email.com';
        u.IsActive = true;
        INSERT u;
        return u;
    }

    @TestSetup
    static void makeData() {

        InitSettings.init();

        // Generate an opportunity and a few Contact Handlers
        Opportunity newOpp = new Opportunity(Name = 'Test', StageName = 'Faisabilité', CloseDate = System.today() + 4, Date_ouverture_opportunitee__c = System.today());

        INSERT newOpp;
    }

    @isTest
    static void testFUCPCreatesAllAccounts() {
        Opportunity opp = [SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Opportunity];

        User adminUser = createUser();

        System.runAs(adminUser){
            Test.startTest();
            Integer previous = [SELECT COUNT() FROM Account];
            UserHandler.fullUserCreationPath(opp, true, returnContactWrappers());
            Integer post = [SELECT COUNT() FROM Account];
            System.assertEquals(previous + 2, post, 'Method should add 2 Accounts');
            Test.stopTest();
        }
    }
}
```

Extract from the permission set xml :

```
    <hasActivationRequired>false</hasActivationRequired>
    <license>Partner Community</license>
```

Extract of profile I assign to user (and therefore user license type)

```
    <custom>true</custom>
    <userLicense>Partner Community</userLicense>
```

As you can see the license types are the same

Comment: Are you able to edit your post and include your test code?

Comment: I would, but the test creates a user, which in turn triggers another class. Still, I'll edit and post the test methods

Comment: Somewhere within the test code, one or more Users are being created with a User License Type not matching the User License associated with the Permission Set you are attempting to apply. The code included in your question does not show the code that creates the Users or assigning them the Permission Set. Can you [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/341245/edit) and include this code?

Comment: Yes the users are created within the method `UserHandler.fullUserCreationPath`. The license type assigned to the users is the same as the license type of the permissions sets, as I do not have the error when assigning them from an anonymous apex block.
The only difference to what I usually do is that the code is executed in a test class.
I am wondering if users created in test classes have a license

Comment: @TSmith Added the edit nevertheless